# POSIX regex expression with grouping not working as expected

Tags: regex, posix

I want to have a posix regex such if there's a digit in the end it is not included in the first group. Example:

```
abc  -> group1:"abc" group2:""
def0 -> group1:"def" group2:"0"
```

I tried this: `(\S+)([0-9]+)?`
However this one returns:

```
abc  -> group1:"abc" group2:""
def0 -> group1:"def0" group2:""
```

How can I make second group more greedy than the first group?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... `\s` stands for “whitespace character”, and capitalizing it negates it, so `\S` means "any non-whitespace character". If what you want is to match alpha strings only, and not numeric, you can use the class (or a shortcut if your RE parser has one) just for that:

```
$ printf 'abc123\ndef0\n' | sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]*)(.*)/group1: \1 group2: \2/'
group1: abc group2: 123
group1: def group2: 0
```